# Magento 404 error page not found after cache cleaning

Tags: magento

I’ve looked everywhere and try many things. I’ve got Magento installed on a local server.

Windows 2003 with Apache 2.2.17. I’m using wamp.

If I clear the cache folders, I’ve got a error 404 page not found (home + admin) and each time I need to reinstall. I've checked on mysql and everything seems to be fine (core_config_data)

Does someone has a idea of what happened.

Thanks

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled and is Magento configured to use them?